# Analyzing Ryuichi Sakamoto's "Ballet Mécanique" 3

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, harmony, chord-progressions

[image]

[image]

(listen from 2:31)

I don't get how from the [D] part's last bar BbM7 (IV)

you could go to the [E] part (Ab/C).

And if you see the [E] part, you could see that I analyzed it as a modulation to Ab Major key.

Because if you see the [F] part, you could see that the chords and the melodies are the same as the [E] part.

So my interpretation is, from the [D] part ( F Major key ), It suddenly modulated to Ab Major key.

But How?..

How did he just went from the [D] part's BbM7 (IV) and just suddenly modulate to the Ab key ?

Comment: This is your third or fourth post regarding the same collection of pieces.  Please try to ask one question, learn from it, and apply that knowledge to subsequent analyses

Comment: @CarlWitthoft But I thought you have to write about one question at a time. Thats why I divided all the question from the same piece..and they're all different type of harmonic movement so how am i supposed to learn from just one question?

Comment: @HyunYooPark I think maybe Carl is right on this one. Usually pieces that need multiple clarifications get combined into one question.

Comment: But I got told that you should ask question individually on https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/66524/analyzing-hisaishi-joes-song-reprise

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the concept of [direct modulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation_(music)#Phrase_modulation). Also sometimes called "phrase modulation," it's a modulation that's created with no harmonies to connect the first key with the second. Instead, the music just abruptly switches and is magically in a new key without any harmonic transition.

It sounds to me like that's all that's happening here: we end a phrase and we suddenly move to A♭ major.

This is really common in popular music, where these phrase modulations often move up by [half step](https://youtu.be/ISBOIMhWWFA?t=2m52s).

Comment: But how do you see at as a "end a phrase" if it ends with BbM7 ( IVM7, SubDominant ) instead of a Tonic ?